# Don't understand the meaning of 'killer' here

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is a "killer start-up"? Does the word "killer" have the direct meaning in this case like startup is intended to kill somebody for money?

> Voice to text is cool and does have a place, but more often than not speaking messages aloud is inappropriate or undesirable (you don't want everyone to hear about the killer new start-up you're investing in, lol.)

Comment: Hello EdwardL! Please look up "killer" or "kill" in a dictionary, or a few dictionaries, and see if you find a definition that makes sense to you. If you have difficulty with that, let us know what research you did, what you found, and why you still have a question. If you can find the answer in a dictionary, it is off-topic for English Language Learners. For more information, please see help, below, asking, then "What topics can I ask about here?" Of course your questions are always welcome. [Voting to close; this should be readily answerable for most ELLs by consulting a dictionary.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, 'killer' just means 'great'. Your start-up is 'killer' as in it's going to 'make a killing', slang for making lots of money.

The sentence is saying you don't want people to overhear your idea which is going to make you a lot of money, likely so they can't take your idea.

Comment: It's worth noting that *to kill* (and related forms) is used more generally as a slang term with a positive connotation. E.g. "He's a killer musician." or "That comedian totally killed last night."

Comment: Good point! I definitely overlooked that for some reason...

Comment: Within the startup / venture capital communities, the "killer app" is what everyone is pursuing - the next billion-dollar idea.

Answer (score -1):

A "Killer Start-up" could also denote the intention to remove a kind of industry. For example, some may say that Netflix killed Blockbuster and other video rental stores that used to exist. Apple's iTunes killed record stores.

Thus, the death could be about an industry as sometimes a new product or service can replace existing ones.

Comment: I thought about it too, but I guess we were mistaken))